# type -p java does not work in a init.d script

Tags: debian, bash, java, init.d

I am trying to modify `/etc/init.d/jenkins` script, in order to add my custom java path. My solutions is this:

```
JAVAPATH=$(type -p java) 
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:$JAVAPATH
```

However, when I start the service and look into the logs, I see JAVAPATH variable is empty. On the other hand, if I write, for instance:

```
PYPATH=$(type -p python) 
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:$PYPATH
```

Then PATH variable will include python binary perfectly.

My final goal is removing the file name, just saving dirname so:

`JAVAPATH=$(type -p java | xargs dirname)`

On my custum scripts and tests, everything works fine, so I assume there is something with java that I don't know. I'm running a Debian 10 and my java path is `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.9/bin/java`

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: `PATH` should not contain paths to binaries (like `java` and `python`), it should contain paths to *directories* that the binaries are in. Furthermore, `type -p` will only find paths to binaries *in directories that're already in `PATH`* (i.e. those that don't need to be added because they're already there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`type` is a shell builtin that looks for a file in every directory specified in your `$PATH` variable.

In your example it's not showing anything because there's no `java` binary in any of the directories specified in your `$PATH`.

On the contrary, `python` is being found because it is indeed in the one of youyr `$PATH` directories (specifically in `/usr/bin`).

I don't know what installation method for Java you've used, but you could try to use `/etc/alternatives/java` as it is usually configured to point to the default java binary in your system.

Another not-so-clean option is to use `dpkg -L <java package name>` to list all the files provided by your jdk and filter them to find the binary you want to use:

```
$ JAVA_PATH=$(dpkg -L openjdk-11-jre-headless|fgrep bin/java)
$ echo $JAVA_PATH
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
```

Comment: After a deeper research, I've read init.d scripts should set it's own env variables for security reasons, so hardcoding path is it a good practice at all. Thanks for your response.